# How risky is it to try a dog shock collar (e-collar) on yourself?

Tags: burns

OK, so this might sound highly masochistic but that's not for my personal enjoyment.

As a dog trainer I strongly advocate against the use of shock/electric/remote collar and I arrived at the idea that a video showing such a collar on a human would make a strong point. Indeed many people using these are saying that it is not that bad for the dog, which I really don't believe to be true.

So are there actual risk (electrocution, burns, etc.) on demonstrating that on myself?

I certainly wouldn't start on my neck, maybe on my leg?

Comment: I'll assume the collar has a DC voltage of X volts. If the voltage is high enough a detectable current will run through your leg. This current may be higher in you than in a dog, depending on how dog skin/fur contribute to resistance. So the comparison may be flawed, you also need to account for different pain thresholds between species.

Comment: You can see hundreds of people trying this on youtube. I'm slightly embarrassed that I know this...

Comment: @TTT I'm embarrassed I didn't have a look at YT first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one off experiment, a search of [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dog+shock+collar+on+man)  suggests that while uncomfortable, testing a dog shock collar on yourself is not particularly risky. That said, if you wish to avoid the discomfort, existing videos might get the point across.